# Won't Print Out

Tags: javascript

The object method does not print out in HTML. Does anyone know why this code below is not working?

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor)
{
this.firstname = firstname;
this.lastname = lastname;
this.age = age;
this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
this.printing = function print(){
id = for(var x = 0;x < person.length; x++){
document.getElementById('main_div').innerHTML = person[x];
}
};
}

var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");

myFather.printing;
```

Comment: you forgot the `()` to actually execute the function:  `myFather.printing()`

Comment: `id = for`... looks like a syntax error to me.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of errors.

1) `id = for(var x = 0;x < person.length; x++){` does not mean anything. You cannot assign the value of for loop to a variable. So just remove the `id =` part.

2) You are not calling your function. So change the last line to `myFather.printing()`.

edit. and you can also change `this.printing = function print(){` to just `this.printing = function() {` because the name `print` is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the function. Try `myFather.printing();` - those parentheses call the function (in this case, with no arguments)